# Activating NightMode (Do Not Disturb) at a designated time of night?

Tags: software-recommendation, notifications, ios, do-not-disturb

I am often on call for work, if my phone rings it's very important that I can answer it. I set the ringer on loud when I go to bed to wake me if called.

However the contract only covers certain times so I don't want to be distracted by every notification/message coming in when I am not on duty.

Is it possible to configure Night Mode to come on automatically at (for example) midnight?

I've looked into some of the Alarm/Timer functions which offer a few options "When Alarm  Ends" but I've not seen what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do Not Disturb has Manual or Timer modes, though it is fixed times, not 'until alarm goes off'

Details at [Use Do Not Disturb on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5463?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

With Do Not Disturb, you can silence calls, alerts, and notifications that you get while your device is locked. You can also schedule a time or choose who you'll allow calls from.

**Turn Do Not Disturb on or off**

When Do Not Disturb is on, a crescent moon  , or half-moon, icon will appear in the status bar. There are two ways to turn Do Not Disturb on or off:

- Tap Settings > Do Not Disturb. Choose Manual to turn on Do Not Disturb now or set a schedule.
- Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open Control Center. Tap the crescent moon.

**Set a schedule**

If you don't want to be disturbed at a certain time, you can set a schedule. Tap Settings > Do Not Disturb and turn on Scheduled. Then set a time.
Schedule Do Not Disturb time

**Change your settings**

You can also choose when you want to be disturbed:

- Allow Calls From: Allow calls from everyone, no one, your favorites, or specific contact groups stored on your device or your iCloud account.
- Repeated Calls: If someone calls you twice within three minutes, the call won't be silenced.
- Silence: Choose to silence calls and notifications always or only when the device is locked.